# How to store sql query output in variable in shell script

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am trying to store the value of sql query output in a variable using shell script.

```
size=`${PATH_TO_CLIENT}sqlplus $IMPUSER/$IMPPWD@$ENDPOINT<< EOF
select owner, sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 Size_GB from dba_segments where owner = 'XXXX' group by owner;
exit;
EOF`
echo "Total data is ${size}"
```

The output I am getting is

```
**Total data is**
SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri May 14 11:06:42 2021
Version 21.1.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri May 14 2021 11:01:02 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.8.0.0.0

SQL>
OWNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIZE_GB
----------
XXXXXXX
12.2345


SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.8.0.0.0
```

Inside the variable full connection string and sql query output all are getting stored. I just want to get value like ***$size=12.2345*** Please tell me how to get that

Comment: you should remove `${PATH_TO_CLIENT}` which precedes `sqlplus` command by properly setting `ORACLE_HOME` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output is consistent with newlines, you could use:

```
size=`${PATH_TO_CLIENT}sqlplus $IMPUSER/$IMPPWD@$ENDPOINT<< EOF | sed -n '/^\s*SIZE_GB$/{n;n;n;p}'
select owner, sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 Size_GB from dba_segments where owner = 'XXXX' group by owner;
exit;
EOF`
```

It will return the third line after line which contains 'SIZE_GB'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
size=`${PATH_TO_CLIENT}sqlplus -s $IMPUSER/$IMPPWD@$ENDPOINT <<EOF
set echo off
set feedback off
set heading off
set pages 0
select sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 Size_GB from dba_segments where owner = 'SYS';
exit;
EOF`
echo "Total data is ${size}"
```

Comment: this worked but the value was coming in newline after the total data statement ```Total data is =
11.2105713```

Comment: Just add one more line after set heading off          
    "set pages 0". I have updated the answer above.

Answer (score 3):

The size value might be assigned to the current variable through use of the following code block

```
size=$(sqlplus -S /nolog << EOF
 conn $IMPUSER/$IMPPWD@$ENDPOINT
 whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
 SET PAGES 0
 SELECT SUM(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 FROM dba_segments WHERE owner = 'XXXX';
EOF
)
echo "Total data is "$size
```

where

- keeping `owner` column and `group by` clause are redundant as
  returning only one column value for a single schema
- no need to alias the calculated value as not needed for the returning result while hiding the column title through use of `SET PAGES 0` command
- using direct connection is not safe, but use `sqlplus -S /nolog` before
  schema connection in order to hide the password while listed by
  anbody through `ps` command.